# Why initial value of dropdown not set in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-final-form, final-form

Could you please tell me why my initial value is not set in react ?I am using `react-final-form`

Here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-star-1qcw3

My initial value is printed in console but not set on dropdown

API link of react final form

https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/examples

```
const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("urllll");

    // (async () => {
    //   setOptions(await getDropDowOptions(dataKey));
    // })();
    console.log(options);
    console.log(value);
    (() => {
      setOptions(getDropDowOptions(dataKey));
    })();
  }, []);





const getDropDowOptions = dataKey => {
  console.log(dataKey);
  switch (dataKey) {
    case "abc":
      console.log("========");
      const slots = [
        {
          key: "9-13",
          label: "09:00-13:00",
          value: "09:00-13:00"
        },
        {
          key: "13:00-16:00",
          label: "13:00-16:00",
          value: "13:00-16:00"
        },
        {
          key: "16:00-19:00",
          label: "16:00-19:00",
          value: "5000"
        }
      ];
      return slots;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are initializing your state to be an empty array, which yields an empty array to be filtered/found when setting the `defaultValue` in `AutoComplete`. Moving the option populating directly into the initial value of state does the trick for me in your sandbox.

```
const [options, setOptions] = useState(getDropDowOptions(dataKey));
```

[image: Edit festive-rgb-or6xh]

My guess is the effect is triggered on first render and sets some state, but that state is not available until the next render cycle, i.e. the second render. By then the select has already set it's default value (from during the first render when it was mounted).

Comment: what about `async` request

Comment: see `options.find is not a function`

Comment: What about `async` request? Are you asking about setting some "initial" state after mounting and fetching some data?

Comment: see my code sand box..let take example I am getting data from server ..but I know what is my inital value

Comment: after `5` second I am getting the data from server . not I want to set my value ?

Comment: is it possible to set value after retrieve fata from server

Comment: The react `useState` hook doesn't work like that. It isn't initial state ready to use on the first render then. Either fetch the options in the parent ahead of time and *then* when ready, pass them to and render the child, **or** use the effect hook as you have "on mount", disable the input, and update the selected option when state has "resolved" and enable the input.

Comment: can you please upate ..it will be help for me

Comment: how ? can you please give example

Comment: can you please give example of this `use the effect hook as you have "on mount", disable the input, and update the selected option when state has "resolved" and enable the input.`

Comment: Convert from uncontrolled to controlled input, with loading and local state. Updated my linked sandbox.